# Why flask app context is lost in child thread when application factory pattern is used?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

Somewhat a mystery question.

Spawning a thread from flask app works well works well when all code is placed in the single `app.py` file, but application context gets lost when factory pattern is used.

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/XXX/flaskthreading/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1008, in __call__
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Jun/2022 14:06:53] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
    return self.registry[key]
KeyError: <greenlet.greenlet object at 0x7f4f541ad040 (otid=0x7f4f54199d00) current active started main>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/XXX/flaskthreading/app2/views.py", line 12, in printer
    print(User.query.all())
  File "/XXX/flaskthreading/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 552, in __get__
    return type.query_class(mapper, session=self.sa.session())
  File "/XXX/flaskthreading/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 47, in __call__
    sess = self.registry()
  File "/XXX/flaskthreading/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1010, in __call__
    return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
  File "/XXX/flaskthreading/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 4225, in __call__
    return self.class_(**local_kw)
  File "/XXX/flaskthreading/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 174, in __init__
    self.app = app = db.get_app()
  File "/XXX/flaskthreading/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1042, in get_app
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.
```

Any idea why is this happening or what docs we have missed ?
MVP provided https://github.com/bodik/flaskthreading-experiments/

```
git clone
pip install -r requirements.txt

# working app
FLASK_APP=app1 flask run
curl http://localhost:5000/

# produces error
FLASK_APP=app2.app flask run
curl http://localhost:5000/
```

Comment: Could you please add a minimum code sample that provokes your error?

Comment: the code is available at https://github.com/bodik/flaskthreading-experiments/. i've added usage example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/reqcontext/#lifetime-of-the-context:

> When a Flask application begins handling a request, it pushes a request context, which also pushes an app context. When the request ends it pops the request context then the application context.
>
> The context is unique to each thread (or other worker type). ...

In the case of a global `app` and `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`, `db` always has `self.app`.
In the case of application factory pattern, `db` gets the app context from the thread.

Pass an `AppContext` to be pushed onto the thread:

```py
# def printer():           # Change this
def printer(app_context):  # to this
    app_context.push()     #
    print(User.query.all())

@blueprint.route('/')
def index():

    # athread = Thread(target=printer, args=(), daemon=True)                          # Change this
    athread = Thread(target=printer, args=(current_app.app_context(),), daemon=True)  # to this
    athread.start()

    return 'ok'
```